# Why does this button still has SPACE on top after setting margin-top to ZERO?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The example can be found at  http://www.bootply.com/143jVqzP0A#

The button looks like this

[image: picture]

which has margin at top, though I set `margin-top` to 0. And I want  the button to fill the whole block vertically, which has no margin or space between the button and its parent block.

Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the padding of h2. Try this:

```
.filter h2{ padding: 0; margin:0; margin-left: 3px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have used

`display:inline-block`,

give `vertical-align:top`

to the button. It would solve the issue. Also you can try giving the `vertical-align:top` to `h2` also.

Answer (score 1):

Set margin to negative...

```
margin-top: -10px; //change value accordding to your preference.
```

Hope it helps;

Answer (score 1):

`button` is an `inline` element by default.
That's why it takes some spaces vertically for the previous and next lines of texts (if there is any).

You might want to apply `display: block;` and `float: left;` to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" style="margin-top: 0; height:28px">
```

The

```
<h2>Factors</h2>
```

element is 28 pixels tall and is stretching the divide (and background) that contains the button. Adding a few pixels to the top.

Alternatively, remove the h2 tag from that container.

Answer (score 0):

at this rule at bootstrap.min.css:

```
.btn-xs, .btn-group-xs > .btn
```

You must to set padding to 0 and looks good.